# how to simulate long press using AndroidViewClient-5.5.1

Tags: key-events, androidviewclient

i want to simulate long press on power key using AndroidViewClient , i could achieve this using monkeyrunner . code is as follows :

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10,'840615d')
device.press("KEYCODE_POWER", MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
```

please help ...

```
Android API - kitkat (19)
AndroidViewClient version - 5.5.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version (**AndroidViewClient 6.0.0**) provides a new (*an experimental*) `AdbClient.longPress(name)` method, which has an special workaround for the `POWER` case as it seems `input keyevent --longpress POWER` does not work as expected.

You can try:

```
device.longPress('POWER')
```

and see if it works.
If it does not, please read the comments in that method and follow the instruction to create a bug report that could add support for your device too.